# Populating Select Combobox Form from external CSV file

Tags: javascript, ajax, csv, combobox, populate

I'm using this code to import a CSV into a var using ajax, then, split the informatión delimited by the "\n" and then populate a Select Box I have in a form.

The CSV is pretty much flat, just 1 column with several rows. Added an alert to monitor the progress.. it all goes fine except when it comes to populate the combobox, instead of populating the String Content, it populates the number of row, for some reason the array is not recording string but row number.

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    url: 'URL CSV',
    success: function(data) {

        alert(data);

        var splitData=data.split("\n");

        for(pn in splitData){

            alert(splitData);

            $('#Entry_ID').append("<option value=\""+pn+"\">"+pn+"</option>");
        }
    }
});
</script>

(the form combobox code)

<select name="Entry.ID" id="Entry_ID" aria-required="true"></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is in the "for..in" loop. A code like this:

```
var arr = ["q", "w", "e"];
for (var i in arr) {
    console.log(i)
}
```

will output:

```
0
1
2
```

The for..in loop takes the key of each item in the object and it is assigned to the var. In an array the key is its position.

The method split of String returns an array with all the items. To loop through the splitData array you can:

```
for (var i = 0; i < splitData.length; i++) {
    alert(splitData[i]);
    $('#Entry_ID').append("<option value=\"" + splitData[i] + "\">" +
        splitData[i] + "</option>");
}
```

or

```
splitData.forEach(function (item) {
    alert(item);
    $('#Entry_ID').append("<option value=\"" + item + "\">" + item + "</option>");
});
```

Comment: You were totally right, just had to add a couple of }} to end the function.